# YEOMAN что это и для чего?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Что такое YEOMAN где это используется, и как начать с ним работать? Искал в интернете слишком сложно, можно объяснить для чайника :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это консольная утилита написанная на Node.js. 
В процессе написания приложение часто необходимо повторять одну и ту же конструкцию(создавать контроллеры, модели, миграции, сиды) кода. Грубо говоря YeoMan генерирует шаблонный код тем самым автоматизирует работу. У YeoMan есть репозитории с генераторами. Берёте генератор -> генерируете -> получаете шаблонный код -> профит.

Подробнее(с установко и примерами) на [habr.com](https://habr.com/ru/post/246349/)

Comment: Я так понял она создает код js под определённые задачи?

Comment: @Alexander да, но не обязательно JS.

Comment: а какие ещё языки поддерживает?

Comment: @Alexander а это не важно. YeoMan это инструмент для генерации кода. Он просто делает всё то что ему говорит генератор из репозитория.